# Add class to a div in header from template file in Wordpress with filter

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a div in header.php like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">Some text</div>
```

I want to add a class to that div from a template/template-part file based on data/logic i have in the template file. I tried creating filter like this:

```
add_filter( 'toggler_class', 'my_class_add',10, 1 );
function my_class_add($class='') {
    echo 'class="'.$class.'"';
}
```

And in header.php i had:

```
<div id="myDiv" <?php apply_filters('toggler_class', ''); ?> >Some text</div>
```

Which prints:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="">Some text</div>
```

This works; but now I want to modify that filter in a template file so that the div gets a new class:

```
<div id="myDiv" class="myNewClass">Some text</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain what you're wanting to happen better? Are you trying to add different classes based on different conditions? Is there a reason you can't just use jQuery for this?

Comment: Where is your function getting it's `class` from?  I don't see any reference anywhere in the code where it would determine when it should or should not add `myNewClass` - what are the conditions for adding it?